# Два блока, один с фиксир шириной, другой "резиновый"

Tags: css, css3

Очень простой вопрос. Есть два блока оба `display:inline-block`, один из блоков с фиксированной шириной в `48px`, другой необходимо сделать "резиновым" (в нем изображение), чтобы при изменении области экрана он вел себя как `width:100%` но с вычетом 48px. Можно ли как-то это сделать без `float` и `calc()`?

Пример: http://jsfiddle.net/4c9x5dyu/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/enna8cjj/ - можно если использовать display: table

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/duLw48kq/ другой вариант.

Comment: Еще вариант http://jsfiddle.net/4c9x5dyu/1/

Comment: Спасибо всем кто откликнулся, остановился на варианте @soledar10 `table-cell`, весьма не плохой вариант у @Vitaliy Shevchenko спасибо вам! 
@soledar10 оформите ответ пож-та

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого используйте `display: table`

http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/enna8cjj/

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.wrap {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.a, .b {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.a {
    width: 48px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color:red;
}
.b {
    background: #ccc;
}
.b img {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="b">
        <img src="http://www.ac-grenoble.fr/ien.vienne1-2/spip/IMG/bmp_Image004.bmp" />
    </div>
</div>
```